# How to make conic-gradient css from the first image into the second image

Tags: css

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aV6k.png)

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqyH1.png)

I want to make a conic gradient from the first image blury like the second image. Can you help me, please?

Here is my conic gradient code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="background: conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, #020031 0deg, #090035 19.68deg, #2B045E 29.09deg, #3E0578 37.08deg, #7708BE 44.38deg, #C80EEC 108.66deg, #E839DE 147.4deg, #F35AAA 159.09deg, #F8668A 168.49deg, #FFA290 179.83deg, #FE8E68 180deg, #FF8134 191.01deg, #FFB97D 192deg, #F7BD4F 206.51deg, #F3C07A 219.02deg, #EBD4C3 226.4deg, #DEDFE3 246.49deg, #D8E7F8 269.42deg, #94D7FC 277.72deg, rgba(0, 156, 233, 0.87) 306.55deg, #0058AA 308.44deg, #02205D 321.45deg, #020031 360deg); width: 200px; height: 200px;">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's possible to some degree with filter blur:

`filter: blur(3px);`

However, fading the gradients in to one another is more complicated and would need to be done in the steps of conic-gradient. Each step should fade smoothly in to the next colour. You can use a css gradient generator to play around with the steps and smooth out the fade https://cssgradient.io/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="filter: blur(3px); background: conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, #020031 0deg, #090035 19.68deg, #2B045E 29.09deg, #3E0578 37.08deg, #7708BE 44.38deg, #C80EEC 108.66deg, #E839DE 147.4deg, #F35AAA 159.09deg, #F8668A 168.49deg, #FFA290 179.83deg, #FE8E68 180deg, #FF8134 191.01deg, #FFB97D 192deg, #F7BD4F 206.51deg, #F3C07A 219.02deg, #EBD4C3 226.4deg, #DEDFE3 246.49deg, #D8E7F8 269.42deg, #94D7FC 277.72deg, rgba(0, 156, 233, 0.87) 306.55deg, #0058AA 308.44deg, #02205D 321.45deg, #020031 360deg); width: 200px; height: 200px;">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```